# What islam says about agnostic Muslims?

Tags: jannah

> Agnostic
>
> > a person who believes that nothing is known or can be known of the existence or nature of God.

So can a Muslims who is agnostic go to heaven?

Comment: Such a person denies revelation, he is a disbeliever.

Comment: @UmH agnostic just believe that maybe God exists and maybe God have send the revelation. For them it is 50/50.

Comment: @UmH unlike us that believe 100% God exists

Comment: Doubt is a type of disbelief. https://islamqa.info/en/answers/243974/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mathematical approach:**

Viewed from the point that by 50% probability God exists, the probability that this person comes to heaven is 25%:

By 50% disbelieve, heaven does not exist.
For the 50% belief, there would be a 50% probability that God would accept him as a believer.

**More serious:**

God will decide. There is no promise that a disbeliever will enter heaven. But God can decide to help this person to believe, if He wills and if the person accepts His guidance.

Ali-i-Imran 3:74

> His mercy for whomever He wills. God is Possessor of Sublime Grace.

There is an old promise from the Tanakh; although revealed to the Jews, it may apply to us, too:

Jeremie 29:11-14a

> For I know the plans I have for you, says the LORD, plans for welfare
> and not for evil, to give you a future and a hope. Then you will call
> upon me and come and pray to me, and I will hear you. You will seek me
> and find me; when you seek me with all your heart, I will be found by
> you, says the LORD.